# Third Party Apps cant get wifi SSID

Tags: applications, wi-fi, connection-issues, xiaomi, 9.0-pie

This is the my first time asking in this SE site.
I have a Xiaomi Redmi 6 Pro running MIUI custom from Xiaomi.eu.
The problem is that in every app (third party apps) that uses Wifi, the SSID is not shown.
It may look like nothing but I have problems with many DashCam apps that don't even connect.
I know I must open an issue to the site where I got the ROM, but I don't know if its directly related to the ROM modification or is a permission that needs to be fixed. I tried to wipe completely my phone but nothing. Even after several updates, same problem. This started when I got Android P.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is most likely the result of an update to the Android SDK that app developers haven't addressed.

Starting in Android P, there were changes to the way apps can retrieve WiFi information.

See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all

> Similar restrictions also apply to the `getConnectionInfo()` method,
>   which returns a `WifiInfo` object describing the current Wi-Fi
>   connection. You can only use this object's methods to retrieve SSID
>   and BSSID values if the calling app has the following permissions:
>
> - ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> - ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
>
> Retrieving the SSID or BSSID also requires location services to be
>   enabled on the device (under Settings > Location).

In your device settings, double check to make sure the apps in question are granted location permissions.  You can also go into app permissions and select "All Permissions" to view exactly what the app requests.

If you don't see the above permissions, plus location permission, then probably the app developer needs to issue an update to their app.  Don't be afraid to contact them through their support channels and inquiry about updates - sometimes they are fairly responsive.

Comment: This was all I needed to know, thanks